# React bizchart add axis name

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript, bizcharts

Im using my react project for **[biz-chart](https://bizcharts.net/gist/2kSfssMubXb)** , i have some conflict on the adding X and Y axis to name, anyone know how to added this correctly ?

**here the image description**
[image]

**[live sample code here](https://bizcharts.net/gist/2kSfssMubXb)**

Thanks

**code here**

```
import React from "react";
import {
  G2,
  Chart,
  Geom,
  Axis,
  Tooltip,
  Coord,
  Label,
  Legend,
  View,
  Guide,
  Shape,
  Facet,
  Util
} from "bizcharts@3.5.8";
import DataSet from "@antv/data-set";

class Groupedcolumn extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const data = [
      {
        name: "London",
        "Jan.": 18.9,
        "Feb.": 28.8,
        "Mar.": 39.3,
        "Apr.": 81.4,
        May: 47,
        "Jun.": 20.3,
        "Jul.": 24,
        "Aug.": 35.6
      },
      {
        name: "Berlin",
        "Jan.": 12.4,
        "Feb.": 23.2,
        "Mar.": 34.5,
        "Apr.": 99.7,
        May: 52.6,
        "Jun.": 35.5,
        "Jul.": 37.4,
        "Aug.": 42.4
      }
    ];
    const ds = new DataSet();
    const dv = ds.createView().source(data);
    dv.transform({
      type: "fold",
      fields: ["Jan.", "Feb.", "Mar.", "Apr.", "May", "Jun.", "Jul.", "Aug."],
      // 展开字段集
      key: "月份",
      // key字段
      value: "月均降雨量" // value字段
    });
    return (
      <div>
        <Chart height={400} data={dv} forceFit>
          <Axis name="月份" />
          <Axis name="月均降雨量" />
          <Legend />
          <Tooltip
            crosshairs={{
              type: "y"
            }}
          />
          <Geom
            type="interval"
            position="月份*月均降雨量"
            color={"name"}
            adjust={[
              {
                type: "dodge",
                marginRatio: 1 / 32
              }
            ]}
          />
        </Chart>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can add a title to the Axis component

```
title={{
         autoRotate: true, // 是否需要自动旋转，默认为 true
         offset: 40, // 设置标题 title 距离坐标轴线的距离
         textStyle: {
             fontSize: '12',
             textAlign: 'center',
             fill: '#999',
             fontWeight: 'bold',
         },
         position: 'center', // 标题的位置，**新增**
     }}
```

Comment: No context provided for the question, explain what you are trying to do.